# Wrong font colour in GNOME's Application menu while in dark mode

Tags: linux, gnome, fonts, pop-os, theme

I installed GNOME Tweaks through the Pop Shop to play around with the customizability.
Under Appearance>Themes>Applications I tried switching it to some of the other preinstalled themes. But after I set it back to the theme I was using before (Pop-dark), I noticed the font colour in the 'Show Applications' menu stayed black, instead of going back to white.

None of the other themes (even the dark ones) seem to change the font colour either.

I tried to reinstall the Pop-Dark theme, but I'm not sure if I even did that right. I have tried to look at what I understand is the CSS code for the theme, at /usr/share/themes/. But my tinkering with it had no effect (I undid all the changes I made). I've uninstalled and reinstalled GNOME Tweaks several times, and rebooted my computer.

I'm not very experienced with Linux, and I'm not to sure how to go about fixing this. I just want the to return back to the default dark Pop OS theme, and have the font colour in the applications menu be white as it was before.

I'm using Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS, and the themes I have preinstalled are:

- Adwaita
- Adwaita-dark
- Default
- Emacs
- HighContrast
- Pop
- Pop-dark
- Raleigh

I've attached a picture of how my 'Show Applications' menus looks, the black font underneath the icons should be white.

[image: Screenshot of the Application menu, with the black font]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem after installing Tweaks.

This fixed it for me:
https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/2057#issuecomment-1078841563

1. Open Extensions from application launcher
2. Enable User Themes
3. Click gear icon of User Themes
4. Set it also to Pop-dark